# Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting EnvironmentName override default Production value

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

```
var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration((config) =>
    {
        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
    {
        config.SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
        config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    });
```

I add new global env variable in Docker file

```
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Development
```

but my `hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName` is always `Production`

How can I override EnvironmentName in a Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting with default Production value?

Comment: Where are you running your app? From visual studio? The command line on your local machine? Or on a separate server?

Comment: Have you created the project using visual studio?

Comment: Sorry I am running in Docker

Answer (score 0):

Open the json file launchsettings.json, and look for the section: "profiles" -> "your project name" -> "environmentVariables" -> "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" and update this value from "Development" to "Production".

Answer (score 0):

If it is an option you can also use and json config file:

```
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                   .ConfigureHostConfiguration(builder =>
                   {
                       builder.AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json", optional: true);
                   })

{
  "environment": "Development",
}
```